# Facebook graph API: How do I use this in conjunction with my access token?

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Graph API to get the detailed information of a user - I'm just not sure how to use the `api()` method to do this.

I have the access token and the user id, so I assumed this would work like so:

```
$facebook->api($user_id . '?access_token=' . $access_token);
```

But this only yields my basic information, ie;

http://graph.facebook.com/100000631233901

Instead of:

https://graph.facebook.com/100000631233901?access_token=124019494346337|2.AQAhBcKnajHJfO-n.3600.1307088000.1-100000631233901|iPP_cSLCHWPLCcCrF3uSBqzVzwU

How do I use the `api()` method correctly to collect the latter list of information?

---

Update:

I've tried parsing an array of parameters like so:

```
$params = array("access_token" => $token);
$stats = $facebook->api($uid, "post", $params);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($stats);
echo '</pre>';
```

However this gives me the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught OAuthException:
>   (#100) The parameter password is
>   required thrown in
>   /home/projectavian/phoenix/facebook.php
>   on line 543

Comment: What detail information do you want to get from the user?

Comment: Primarily just the info shown on my second link.

Comment: You might find the example included with the library (https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) helpful for this.

Comment: @Matt that example only shows how to get your basic info ie api("/userid");

Comment: From the link we cannot get the idea that what do you want to get. Please specify the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(  
    'message' => 'My Friend\'s',  
    "access_token" => "urtoken",  
    "image" => '@' . realpath('http://mysite/img/img.jpg'); 
);  


$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

this help you add PHoto to you album this is how it works.

if you want any spefic feature ask here

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($facebook->api("/$user_id "));
```

don't use access_token for getting user basic information.

if want to post a message or add photo or somthing like that automatically , then we shall use access_tocken.

```
$facebook->api('/".$user_id."/feed', 'POST', array('message' => 'This post came from my app.'));
```

Comment: Neither of those are what I mean, sorry. I know access token isn't required to get basic info - what I want to do is get the information that's shown in my second link in the question through api().

Comment: $facebook->api("/$user_id", "post", array("access_token" => "access_tocken"));try this code

Comment: can you please tell what are the information you need apart from basic information.

Comment: Ok so lets say information on where someone works; how would I get that using $facebook->api()?

Comment: i hope this tutorial will help you:)                                                                                                                       http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this explains how to get the access token. I already have the access token, I just need to be able to use it in the PHP SDK with $facebook->api();